# Does injectivity imply surjectivity for linear maps on subsets of finite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

I would have intuitively thought that the following is true, but I could not find anything by googling it so I got some doubts:

Let $V,W$ finite dimensional normed real vector spaces, and let $U$ be an open, convex subset (which is not necessarily a subspace) of $V$.  Assume there is another open set $O \subset W$, such that there exists a (linear) bijection $B: U \to O$.

Now assume we have a map $$T : U \to O \subset W \\ u \mapsto T(u)$$
such that $T$ is linear on $U$, that is whenever $u,v, (\alpha u + \beta v) \in U$ then $$T(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha T(u) + \beta T(v).$$

**Question:** Does $T$ injective imply $T$ surjective?

As I said, I would have intuitively thought that this should be true under some of the assumptions above. An idea for a proof would be to define dimensions of these open subsets via the dimension of the largest possible vector space intersecting them and then try too carry out the same proof as in the vectorspace-case, but this seems a bit messy. Does anyone have a quick proof or counterexample of the above?

**Edit:** After taking a step back, I think I found an obvious counterexample: If $V=W=\mathbb{R}$, $U= (0,1)$, $O = (0,2)$, then we have a linear bijection via $x\mapsto 2x$ but for example $T:x \mapsto x$ fulfills the assumption but is not surjective. But this leads me to the next question: if we use $U=(0,\infty)$, $O=(-\infty,0)$ an example as above should not be possible. Thus,

**Question 2**: Under what conditions on $U,O$ (exept from them being subspaces) does $T$ injective imply $T$ surjective?

**Edit 2**: I guess now this is true only under very restrictive conditions. Another counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ would be $U = \{(x,y)|x >0, y >0 \}$ and $O = \{(x,y) | x<0, y>0\}$. Then obviously there is a bijection, but $T$ given by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ maps $U$ injectively but not surjectively into $O$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Since you are talking about linear maps, are your subsets presumed to be subspaces?  Or else, what did you mean?  What does "open" mean to you in this context?

Comment: Why do you want "open subsets" for $U,O$? For linear algebra, we would consider subspaces, not just subsets, and  without a topology.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no I don't want subspaces, the question is more that if I know that the restriction of a linear map on some subset maps injectively onto another subset, and there exists some bijection between these two subsets, does this tell us someting about wheter the original map is also surjective. See also the edits above

Comment: Consider a one dimensional space injected into a two dimensional space. Then the one dimensional space is a subset of itself that maps bijectively to a subset of the two dimensional space. Is that map a bijection?

Comment: @JohnDouma I do not exactly follow what you mean?

Comment: The notions of "open" and "convex" don't make sense in arbitrary vector spaces. If you are trying to restrict to some where they have some potentially inherent sense (e.g., $\mathbb{R}^n$), then you need to specify that, or say what  topology and what geometry you are placing on your spaces.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sure I was thinking about $\mathbb{R}^n$, but let's just say the topology comes form some norm. (btw why does convexity not make sense in a vector space)

Comment: "Convex set" is usually defined only in the context of Euclidean spaces, or over an ordered field. If you don't assume you are working over the real numbers, then the definition need not make sense. Remember that the definition is that if $x$ and $y$ are in the set, then **for all $t$, $0\leq t \leq 1$** you also have $tx+(1-t)y$ in the set. If your  field does not have an order, what does  "$0\leq t\leq 1$" even mean?

Comment: Please put *all* your hypotheses in the post; don't bury them in the comment thread.

Comment: I added the restriction to real vector spaces then. In any case, it now seems to me like the assumption will almost always be false even in the simplest examples